# How to add two labels in cell.detailText.label of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way we can add two labels to cell.detailText.label of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.
i want one of them left aligned and other one as right aligned.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

You can't add labels to the detailLabel, but you can add them to the contentView of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 22, 140, 20)];
    UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 22, 140, 20)];

    labelOne.text = @"Left";
    labelTwo.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelTwo.text = @"Right";

    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
}


return cell;
```

}

Comment: Don't want to customize if this is possible without customization

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without cell subview customisation, as yinkou shows ... unless you concatenate the two strings together, and show both text strings on one line:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", firstString, secondString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understand you corretly but maybe you are looking for this:

> UITableViewCellStyleValue1 A style for a cell with a label on the left
>   side of the cell with left-aligned and black text; on the right side
>   is a label that has smaller blue text and is right-aligned. The
>   Settings application uses cells in this style. Available in iOS 3.0
>   and later. Declared in UITableViewCell.h.

Comment: No actuall i have to use Subtitle because that will give me a main Label and a detail label beneath it and in that detail label i want to add another label. I know we can do it if i would come down to customizing but i really don't want it.

Comment: Well I am not sure if you can do it without customization, but that's not a problem, let me know if you need help setting up custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty old question, but I figured I'd chime in anyway.

If you are not using the accessory view of your cell, you can create a UILabel and assign it to the `accessoryView` property. I have done this several times and works well.