# Modified UITableViewCell and unbalanced row-header-row spacing

Tags: uitableview

Previous SO answer ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802543/how-to-add-two-labels-in-cell-detailtext-label-of-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle)) proposed the code below to have right and left justified text in a modification to the Subtitle style tableView cell. I have a spacing problem however when this method of tableview cell modification is used with sections.

The spacing between the second (and greater) header and the last row of the previous section seems to start from the bottom of the unmodified tableviewcell and does not account for the additional labels (see below) impact on cell.contentView. Adjusting row and header height properties does not seem to help, as the spacing is still unbalanced between a section's last row and the section's first row.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 22, 140, 20)];
    UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 22, 140, 20)];

    labelOne.text = @"Left";
    labelTwo.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelTwo.text = @"Right";

    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelOne];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelTwo];
    }

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell and header views are stacked with no spacing between them. So the only way you can pad your content is by adjusting the cell and header heights.

If the layout of your content varies by cell or header such that individual cells and headers need custom heights to get the correct padding, you can specify these by implementing the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate methods in your view controller.

I may be able to give you a more specific answer if you can post more details, e.g. a pic that highlights the problem.